# What is the differential $d^0(f) : C^0(G, A) \to C^1(G, A)$ knowing the general formula?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, homology-cohomology, group-rings

[Romyar Sharifi's Lecture Notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/lecnotes.html)

It's from the first differential formula appearing on page 7 and that formula is:

$$
d^i : C^i(G, A) \to C^{i+1}(G, A), \\
d^i(f)(g_0, \dots, g_i) = g_0 f(g_1, \dots, g_i) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^i (-1)^j f(g_0, \dots, g_{j-2}, g_{j-1}g_j, g_{j+1}, \dots, g_i) + \\
(-1)^{i+1} f(g_1, \dots, g_i)
$$

where $A$ is a $\Bbb{Z}[G]$-module, $G$ is a group, and $C^i(G, A) = \{ f: G^i \to A \vert f \text{ is a } \textbf{function} \}$.

Two questions come to mind in proving that $d^{i+1} \circ d^i = 0$ (i.e. $d$ is indeed a differential of a cochain complex).

1. Does the author really mean "function", i.e. any set map even if it's not a group homomorphism?
2. Given the formula, what is $d^0(f)(g_0)$?

I am not sure about the first, but for the second my guess is:

$$
d^0(f)(g_0) = g_0
$$

Is that correct?

---

Note $G^i = G \times \dots \times G \ (i \text{ times})$.

Comment: 1) yes - function. 2) no... your guess doesn't parse as the new function has to take values in $A$, not in $G$ as you have it: one can  identify $C^0$ with elements of $A$ (the domain is the empty product), and $d^0(a)$ for $a\in A$ has to be element of $C^1$, i.e., a function from $G$ to $A$. Reading the formula you wrote above, one has $d^0(a)(g) = ga - a$.

Comment: @peterag thank you!

Comment: @peterag to check my understanding, since we're a $\Bbb{Z}[G]$-module, that expression is the same as $(g-1)a$?

Comment: yes, if you want.

Comment: @peterag I currently think it's $d^0(a)(g) = g - a$ since in the first term $f(g_1, \dots, g_{i})$, with $i = 0$.

Comment: your last idea can't be right!! How could you subtract an element of $A$ from an element of $G$?  Again, that doesn't parse...  And look at the top of page 8. Really, these are all very 'famous' formulas.

Comment: @peterag you're right.  I discussed this in chat.  You had the formula for $d^0$ correct ! :)

Comment: you betcha I'm right! As I said, these are 'famous' formulas... good luck!

Comment: I'd been hesitating whether to point you at the following, as sometimes it's bad news to try to learn from more than one source at the same time, but... Take a look at Milne's Chapter 2 of https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf for a 'canonical' (so more satisfying) definition of the coho groups. On pages 61++, you will see him matching the canonical definition with 2 different (!!!!) cocycle definitions (so using 2 different delta maps) - one of which is the 'inhomogeneous' one above, and one of which is 'homogeneous' and looks better, and the relation between two.